# NLog entries to SQL Server in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, nlog

What I want to do is to save all my logs to a table in a separate logging database, using NLog, and I can't seem to make it work.

This is my nlog config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    </extensions>

    <!-- the targets to write to -->
    <targets>
        <target name="dbLogger" xsi:type="Database" 
                connectionStringName="LoggingConnection" commandType="StoredProcedure" 
                commandText="[dbo].[NLog_AddEntry_p]">
            <parameter name="@machineName" layout="${machinename}" />
            <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
            <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
            <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
            <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
            <parameter name="@properties" layout="${all-event-properties:separator=|}" />
            <parameter name="@callsite" layout="${callsite}" />
            <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
        </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dbLogger"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I managed to make it log in a .txt file with a similar config, but it does not write to the DB. The "LoggingConnection" connection string is identical to the one I use for normal CRUD operations in the website; the difference is that is uses another DB.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging ? Have you added the nuget-package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/ ?

Comment: Remember that `connectionStringName` only works for NetFramework. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target . Instead use `connectionString` with `${configsetting}` together with UseNLog in  NLog.Web.AspNetCore ver. 4.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some digging checking the internal log file I've come up with this solution.

System.Data.SqlClient was added to the project and it need to be. Also I've added Nlog.Config Nuget package to the project as well.

I've removed the "extension" tag and I've done some tweaks to the nlog tag

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
  autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="false"
  internalLogLevel="Trace" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
```

I've replaced the "connectionStringName" attribute with "connectionString" and added the connection string from the appSettings.json.

Comment: You can use `${configsetting}` to read values directly from appsetting.json. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer (Will automatically register if calling `UseNLog()` from NLog.Web.AspNetCore or NLog.Extension.Hosting)